# Combining two LINQ queries into one

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table that has a about 15 different fields, some of which are JobID (integer field), Cost (integer field) and LastUpdated (DateTime field)

```
JobID  Cost      LastUpdated
 1      10        10-July-2011
 1      15        11-June-2011
 2      25        5-May-2011
 1      15        12-April-2011
```

Is it possible to write one LINQ query to get the sum of Cost for job id = 1 and also the last date such a cost incurred?

The example query output for the sample data above to look like this below:

`40 , 10-july-2011`

Currently I am doing it with two different linq queries like this, resulting in two hits to the database from the website in this particular case.

```
//for last updated
(from row in MyTable where row.JobID == 1
 orderby row.LastUpdated descending
 select row.LastUpdated).First()

//for sum of cost
(from row in MyTable  
 where row.JobID == 1
 select row.Cost).Sum()
```

Will one linq query be better in such a case? Similar cases like this throughout the page load will result in multiple hits to the database, about 18 in all, to 9 different tables. In combining the sum and LastUpdated date in one query I am trying to reduce that hit count to 9, one for each table.

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do a `group` `by` like this

```
var query = from row in MyTable
            group row by row.JobID into rows
            where rows.Key == 1 
            select new
            {
              LastUpdated = rows.Select(x => x.LastUpdated).OrderByDescending(x => x).First(),
              Cost = rows.Sum(x => x.Cost),
            };
```

Comment: I tried this in linqpad .. and got an error : No overload for method 'OrderByDescending' takes 0 arguments.

Comment: however this line which I changed did the trick..  LastUpdated = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated).First().LastUpdated

Comment: @user20358 - sorry I updated to *.OrderByDescending(x => x)* that should work for you now. Your line is also good.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
MyTable.Where(x => x.JobID == 1)
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated)
       .GroupBy(x => x.JobID)
       .Select(x => new { LastUpdated = x.First().LastUpdated, 
                          Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Cost) } );
```

Comment: thanks Daniel for the quick response, dont mean to be rude but just for my understanding how is this query better than the one given by Aducci? I ran both in SQL profiler and they both seem to consume the same amount of cpu and time. However his query seems more readable to me coming from a SQL background. Is this the better way to write Linq queries or should I go with what I find more readable. Again, I dont mean to be rude or question your knowledge. this is just for my understanding... thanks :)

Comment: @user20358: The answers should be equivalent. I personally don't like the query syntax and find it hard to read, that's why I am using method chains. It's a matter of personal preference.